Which functions diverge in the following integral?
We have an integral of a real valued $C^2$ function on real numbers.
The function is also monotonically increasing, and $f(0)=0$. Let $0<a<1.$
The integral:
$$
I= \lim_{s \to 0} \int^{a}_s \left(\frac{f(a)}{f(x)}-1\right)dx
$$
Now we have to figure out what is the class of functions $f$ for which this integral diverges to infinity.
What I have figured out:
The integral $\int_s^ax^{-P}$ diverges if $p\geq1$. Thus, if $\frac{f(a)}{f(x)} - 1 > x^{-1}$, then the integral diverges. That is, roughly speaking if $f$ increases at least as fast as $x$ then the integral diverges.
My question is that can i find a more general condition, or necessary conditions that $f$ satisfies which ensure the divergence?

Let $I_1 = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\int_{s}^{\infty}f(a)/f(x)dx$. Then clearly $I$ converges iif $I_1$ converges
If there exists and $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(\epsilon) = 0$ then the integral diverges.
Otherwise, $f(x)$ is positive on $(0,a]$. Let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f(x)$, then $F(x)$ strictly increases on $(0,1]$. Therefore $F(x)$ is a bijection on $[0,1]$ and $F^{-1}(x)$ also exists. Moreover, $F^{-1}(x)$ also strictly increases. Let $G(x) = f(a)F^{-1}(1/x)$ for $0 < x < a$. We have
$$dG = -\frac{x^2f(a)}{f(x)}dx$$
The integral can be rewritten as
$$I_1 = -\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\int_{G(a)}^{G(s)}{(G^{-1}(x))^{-2}dx}$$
Since $G^{-1}(x)$ strictly decreases and is positive, the expression inside the integral decreases monotonically. This means we can apply the integral test
$$I_1 \text{ converges if } \sum_{i = L}^\infty (G^{-1}(x))^{-2} \text{ converges}$$
Where $L = \lceil G(a)\rceil$

Could you please explain why convergence of I implies convergence of I_1? Also, in the integral after the change of variable, shouldn't the x^2 term be in the denominator? That's what I am getting.

The question mentions that f is monotonically increasing and f(0)=0. It means that f is not zero for any value greater than 0. why are we considering an epsilon value at which it might be zero? Thanks in advance.

@sam yeah I made mistake. I changed the answer accordingly. As for positivity of $f(x)$, it is only guaranteed if $f(x)$ is said to be strictly increasing i.e. $f(x) > f(y)$ if $x > y$, for monotonically increasing function you get the $\geq$ sign.
